# Convergence of ratio of linear combination of iid random variables to their sum

Tags: random-variables

Suppose $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ are i.i.d. normal random variables, $a_1,a_2,...a_n$ are some positive constants. Could we have following equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_ix_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}=O_p(\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}a_i}{n})?$$
How to get this?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please show some of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_ix_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2) /n}{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)/n}
\end{align}

By the strong law of large number, $(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)/n$ converges to 1 almost surely, so we only need to prove $$\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2) /n}{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i) /n} = O_p(1)$$ i.e.

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i} = O_p(1)$$

Since $E\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i} = 1$, we can use 
$$P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i} >M) \leq \frac{1}{M}$$
to conclude